# Accessing particular, the same instance of an object from different java classes

Tags: java, object, instance

- I have 4 different classes: Main, Employee, Company and HRDepartment

  - Class Company stores employees, new instances of Employees are created in this class
  - John Doe instance was created in Company class
  - How to access this particular instance in other classes to change its    fields/invoke methods

Please find code below. Thank you.

```
    public class Main
    {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        HRDepartment hr = new HRDepartment();
        hr.payRenumeration(5000);
        // how to print cash of John Doe? I can't type System.out.println(john_doe.getCash())
        // because this instance was created in another class
      }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
      private double cash;

      public void addCash(double cash)
      {
      this.cash += cash;
      }

      public double getCash()
      {
      return cash;
      }

    }

    public class Company
    {
      // New employee is created in Company system
      Employee john_doe = new Employee();

    }

    public class HRDepartment
    {
       public void payRenumeration(double renumerationToPay)
       {
       // how to access instance john_doe created in Company class?
       // if this was in the same class I could type simply john_doe.addCash(renumerationToPay);
       }

    }
```

Comment: Make a singlton pattern in order to use the same instance between all classes

Comment: `Company` should contain a `Map<String, Employee>` field and a `getEmployee(String name)` method returning the required employee.